# Accessing NS_ENUM of objective-C in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have this `NS_ENUM` called `ObserveType` having two properties called `Observe` and `ObserveAll`. I can access the `ObserveAll` property as you can see from the picture, but I can't access `Observe`.

**The NS_ENUM is in a header file of objective-C.**

I know that changing `Observe` to `ObserveX` or `ObserveXYZ` will work.

But how do I access `Observe` without changing the name of the `Observe`?

**Notice** that I have to access the `Observe` on Swift.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Language Guide - Interoperability - Interacting with C APIs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html):

> *"The prefixes to C enumeration case names are removed when they are imported into Swift, whether they’re defined in system frameworks or
>   in custom code."*

This means your first case in the `ObserveType` enum have no name after being imported to Swift (which I'm somewhat surprised doesn't yield a compile error). If we were to print out the conversion, it would look something like (conceptually)

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, ObserveType) {
   Observe = 0
   ObserveAll = 1
};

// imported like ...
enum ObserveType: Int {
    case _ = 0 // obviously illegal if applied directly in Swift
    case All
}
```

You could try to access the nameless case by using its `rawValue` (`0`), but I would recommend updating the name of the first case in your Obj-C enum, if possible.

```
if let empty = ObserveType(rawValue: 0) {
    print(empty) // prints ""?
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to answers above, I'd like to point out that you can give your Objective-C NS_ENUM a Swift name with `NS_SWIFT_NAME` macro:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, XYZAwesomeEnum) {
    XYZAwesomeEnumA,
    XYZAwesomeEnumB,
    XYZAwesomeEnumC,
} NS_SWIFT_NAME(AwesomeEnum);
```

Use it later in Swift:

```
AwesomeEnum.a
```

[Apple Developer: Renaming Objective-C APIs for Swift](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/objective-c_and_c_code_customization/renaming_objective-c_apis_for_swift)

Answer (score 1):

**dfri**'s answer is spot on, and to extend on his answer, it is probably best to name the enum and its cases following the widely adopted conventions. In the following code, I am making certain guesses on your intention.

```c
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, XYZObserveType) {
    XYZObserveOne,
    XYZObserveAll
}
```

Another tip that I find useful when working with projects contain both Swift and Objective-C code is **[Generated Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0ftt.png)** in the source editor.

When you are viewing an Objective-C class, selecting this option will show you the generated Swift header, which can be helpful in many occasions.